# Print out the kernel for the best SVM classifier found by GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I tested different kernels for a Support vector machine classifier using GridSearchCV. When I tried to print out the best estimator ( see the code below), I got the output:

```
best estimator SVC(C=8, gamma=0.125, probability=True)
```

Code:

```
        kernel=["linear", "rbf"],
        C=[8],
        gamma=[0.125],
        params = dict(kernel=kernel, C=C, gamma=gamma)
        svc = sklearn.svm.SVC(probability=True)
        clf = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(svc, params, n_jobs=nproc, verbose=10)
        clf.fit(self.W[:], self.y[:])
        print('best estimator', clf.best_estimator_)
```

How can I print out the kernel the best estimator used?

Since the kernel is either linear or rbf, I changed kernel = ["linear"] or kernel = ["rbf"] but the best_score I got is different from kernel =["linear", "rbf"]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
clf.best_estimator_.kernel
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?